# Where is there any documentation on what "Active" means in the top left of the Gerrit web interface when viewing a Change?

Tags: gerrit

Where is there any documentation on what "Active" means in the top left of the Gerrit web interface when viewing a Change?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Source:

[change status in Gerrit](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/user-review-ui.html)

The change status shows the state of the change:

- ***Active*:**

  The change is under active review.
- **Merge Conflict:**

  The change can’t be merged due to conflicts.
- **Ready to Submit:**

  The change has all necessary approvals and may be submitted.
- **Merged:**

  The change was successfully merged into the destination branch.
- **Abandoned:**

  The change was abandoned.